# How to add hash at end of URL when clicking on Bootrap-vue tabs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

In my single file Vue component I have:

```
<b-tabs>
  <b-tab title="Exotic Dogs" href="#dogs">
    <br>Dogs here
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="Exotic Cats"  href="#cats">
    <br>Cats here
  </b-tab>

</b-tabs>
```

I am using standard Vue Router and I can access `this.$router` What I want is that when a tab is clicked (or touched ) the URL should be appended #dogs or #cats at the end of current URL depending on which  tab was clicked replacing current hash if any.

The farthest progress I could make is to capture input event defined for tabs component:

```
<b-tabs v-on:input="doShowTab">
 ....

</b-tabs>

....

methods: {
    doShowTab(index) {
      console.log(index)
    },
```

Log prints tab index correctly. How to solve this issue?

My actual tabs code is much complicated showing some tabs and hiding some depending of state. But I have much simplified the code here.

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
<b-tabs ref="tabs" v-on:input="doShowTab">
 ....

</b-tabs>

doShowTab(index) {
  let tabID = this.$refs.tabs.$children.length/2+index;
  let tab = this.$refs.tabs.$children[tabID];
  location.hash = tab.href;
},
```

Comment: I tired your code but I get this error: Error in event handler for "input": "TypeError: Cannot read property '$children' of undefined"

Comment: you should add **ref** _attribute_ with your desired name to **<b-tabs>** component my name was `tabs` so i could access it like `this.$refs.tabs` but it seems you didn't define this reference